# Kafka compression, how to limit it to some listed topics? How to use compressed.topics property using clients produce API?

Tags: apache-kafka, compression

I've enabled kafka message compression from client's producer API like :

configProperties.put(ProducerConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG, "gzip")

It works well, however if we want to limit the above compression to some listed topics, we've notice a way :

configProperties.put("compressed.topics", "topicA,topicB")

from this link :
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Compression .
But it is not working, means in my test case I've enabled compression and I didn't listed my topic in compressed.topics's args. still the compression been applied. please help.

Comment: You need to set `compression.code` according to that wiki page, but I would first check the official configurations on the Kafka website since that wiki page seems to be dated back to Kafka 0.7 release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compression is handled by several parameters in Kafka:

- On the brokers, `compression.type` configures the default for the entire cluster.  It allows the values `gzip`, `snappy`, `lz4`, `uncompressed` or `producer`.  The first three are self-explanatory, they're just different compression methods (snappy/lz4 being the recommended ones), `uncompressed` is self-explanatory, and the default `producer`, which basically is just using whatever compression (or not) the producer decided to use.  In this case, Kafka just sees the messages as byte arrays, and doesn't try to decode them.
- At the topic level on the broker, you can also specify the same configurations as above, `gzip`, `snappy`, `lz4`, `uncompresssed` or `producer`.  They're exactly the same, but act as *overrides* specifically for the topic you set them to.
- On the producer side, in code, you can also set `compression.type`, and the possible values are `gzip`, `snappy`, `lz4` and `none`, where this last one is the default.

You should be looking at the recent documentation for Kakfa.  You don't specify which Kafka version you're using, but assuming a recent one, I would look at these docs:

https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html

In those, there is no mention of `compression.topics` as a configuration option. So, like @cricket_007 mentioned, this is an outdated/stale wiki page that you shouldn't be using.